# Comparing each file in two directories and copying it to another if it differs from its counterpart

Tags: shell, file-copy

How can I compare all files in two directories and copy the ones that are different to another directory? For example, say we have **dir1** and **dir2**:

```
dir1:
     build.gradle
     gradle.properties
     somejar.jar
     javacode.java
     anotherjar.jar

dir2:
     build.gradle      <-- different from build.gradle in dir1
     gradle.properties
     somejar.jar
     javacode.java     <-- different from javacode.java in dir1
     yetanotherjar.jar
```

How may I create a new directory **dir3** that contains the different files from **dir2**, the common files in **dir1** and **dir2** and all uncommon files in both **dir1** and **dir2**? **dir3** should contain:

```
dir3:
     build.gradle      <-- from dir2
     gradle.properties <-- these are common files both in dir1 and dir2
     somejar.jar       <--
     javacode.java     <-- from dir2
     anotherjar.jar    <-- from dir1
     yetanotherjar.jar <-- from dir2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is

```
cp -n dir2/* dir1/* dir3/
```

Answer (score 3):

Do I understand you correctly in that `dir3` should contain all files from the two base directories, and if a file appears in both directories, the one from `dir2` should be taken? Then a simple

```bash
cp dir1/* dir3/
cp dir2/* dir3/
```

should do the trick: Files that differ in both source directories will be overwritten with the version from `dir2`. If you do not want to copy identical files twice, you might also `rsync` them instead of `cp`ing.

Answer (score 0):

`cp -pu dir2/* dir1/* dir3/`

from man:

```
-p    same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
-u    copy only when the SOURCE file is  newer  than  the  destination
      file or when the destination file is missing
```

Note:

1. Always put the updated directory first. (From example above: `cp -pu dir1/* dir2/* dir3/` will not copy the updated files)
2. `dir3` must exist.

Comment: `cp -u` only works if every duplicate file in `dir2` is an edit from the one in `dir1`. If both could have changed independently, it is not clear which one is newer.